# expect scripting with detached screen

Tags: linux, scripting, expect

I've a script that needs to interact with 2 different hosts (client & server), login to them and perform some different commands on both of them concurrently.

I've discovered that expect scripting is useful for the automation process and screen command is useful for creating many windows and interact with them simultaneously.

I used this script and it seems everything is working fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn screen -S server ssh root@194.116.5.80

set timeout 30
expect "assword" { send "toor\r" }
expect -re "(\\\$ |# )"
send "iperf3 -s\r"
interact
```

when I tried to run the screen in deatached mode it didn't work...

I did:

```
spawn screen -d -m -S server ssh root@194.116.5.80
```

but it shows me an error: spawn id exp6 not open.

what can I do to solve this problem ?

as a bottom line I'm in need to use expect with deatached non visible screen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for others facing the same problem, I managed to solve it and I think that the problem was: expect couldn't interact with "what it doesn't see" i.e. with the detached screen.

so I managed to first do everything I want then to detach from the screen to perform another job on another screen.

The script became like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 30

spawn screen -S server ssh <USER_NAME>@<IPADDRESS>

expect "assword" { send "<YOUR_PASSWORD>\r" }

expect -re "(\\\$ |# )"

send "<YOUR_COMMAND>\r"

send "\01d"    # detach from the screen (ctrl-a + d)

interact     # cause the screen not to close.
```

Hope that was useful.